# Why is an @Autowired field within a @Configuration class null?

Tags: java, spring

This is an example from [the Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-core), section 6.12.5:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Bean
    public TransferService transferService() {
        return new TransferServiceImpl(accountRepository);
    }

}
```

My question is: why must it happen that `accountRepository` is created before it's used by `new TransferServiceImpl()`?  Offhand, I don't see how Spring could know that the second one depends on the first one being set up (unless it goes through the `transferService()` bytecode).  Is it because something about the order in which Spring does things guarantees that the `@Autowired` variable is processed before the `@Bean` method could possibly be called?  What is the processing order?  What kinds of circumstances could cause Spring to process these out of order?

The reason I'm asking is that I have a case where something like this isn't working, i.e. the `new` is being executed with a `null` argument.  Either the `@Autowired` variable is being set up too late, or it isn't set up at all (my guess is the latter, based on some `log4j.logger.org.springframework.beans` debugging output, but I'm not sure).  The situation is of course much more complex--it's a largish application, and there are a few more `@Autowired` and `@Bean` definitions in the configuration class.  Using `@DependsOn` hasn't helped.  It will take a lot of time to narrow down the problem by deleting code until I can get a minimal example, but I wanted to see if I could get some insight into the problem by learning more details about how Spring processes things, before starting down the difficult code reduction path.

Comment: In this case, it can't. Instead, inject the `AccountRepository` as a parameter in your `transferService` bean method.

Comment: That's the workaround I ended up doing.  Are you saying that the example in the Spring docs is broken?

Comment: @ajb Please read  6.12.5 fully. The code you have is a sample code only. It mentions about this ambiguity.

Comment: @RamanujanR I had read the paragraph about the ambiguity, but I think the discussion of the ambiguity was ambiguous :)  It looks to me like it was about _where_ the bean was declared, not when the bean was created.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> why must it happen that `accountRepository` is created before it's used
>   by new `TransferServiceImpl()`?

It doesn't. `accountRepository` may be seen to be `null`.

From the note in the [documentation you linked](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-injecting-imported-beans) (its more current version)

> Make sure that the dependencies you inject that way are of the
>   simplest kind only. **`@Configuration` classes are processed quite early
>   during the initialization of the context and forcing a dependency to
>   be injected this way may lead to unexpected early initialization.**
>   Whenever possible, resort to parameter-based injection as in the
>   example above.
>
> Also, be particularly **careful with `BeanPostProcessor`** and
>   `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` definitions via `@Bean`. Those should usually
>   be declared as `static` `@Bean` methods, not triggering the instantiation
>   of their containing configuration class. Otherwise, `@Autowired` and
>   `@Value` won’t work on the configuration class itself since it is being
>   created as a bean instance too early.

In summary, a `Configuration` class will end up being just another bean in the application context. As such, it will be processed by all registered [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) beans.

`@Autowired` is processed by [`AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html). Presumably, you're using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` which registers one automatically.

In your example, which is incomplete since

> ...but determining exactly where the autowired bean definitions are
>   declared is still somewhat ambiguous

However, we can assume some other configuration provided a bean definition for a `AccountRepository` bean. Once the application context instantiates the `ServiceConfig` bean, it can then post process it and inject `@Autowired` targets.

The only reason an `@Autowired` target could be `null` in a `@Configuration` bean instance is that you tried to read it before an `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` could process/inject it.

Consider a circular dependency. Take the `@Configuration` class in your snippet with an additional `@ComponentScan` of the following classes

```
@Component
class AccountRepository {
    public AccountRepository(Foo foo) {}
}
@Component
class Foo {
    public Foo(TransferService ts) {}
}
```

The `@Configuration` bean get initialized. `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` kicks off to process the `accountRepository` field. It looks for an `AccountRepository` bean and tries to initialize it. It needs a `Foo` bean to instantiate it (for constructor injection). It looks for a `Foo` bean and tries to initialize it. It needs a `TransferService` bean to instantiate it (for constructor injection). It looks for a `TransferService` bean and finds the `@Bean` factory method. It invokes it. The `accountRepository` hasn't been initialized yet, so remains `null`. You can verify this by putting a breakpoint in the `@Bean` method and browsing the stack trace.

Had you used a parameter injection as suggested in the quote above

> Whenever possible, resort to parameter-based injection as in the example above.

Spring would've crashed and warned you

> Caused by:
>   `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException`:
>   Error creating bean with name `'accountRepository'`: Requested bean is
>   currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

---

> That's the workaround I ended up doing

I can't currently explain this.

Answer (score 0):

I just move `accountRepository` to the method's param and annotated with `@Autowired` to solve this problem. But I don't know why. I think the reason is about `Spring`'s init order.

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public TransferService transferService(@Autowired AccountRepository accountRepository) {
        return new TransferServiceImpl(accountRepository);
    }

}
```