# Why does parameter injection in Bean A break property resolution Bean B? (Both of type of type PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean, property-placeholder

I have two PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer beans in my project.

Bean A: (Defined as XML)

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"  class="org.jasypt.spring3.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <constructor-arg ref="configurationEncryptor" />
    <property name="order" value="0" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/app-dev.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:/common-dev.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Bean B: (Defined as Java Config)

```
@Bean(name = "customPropertiesUtil")
public static CustomPropertiesUtil customPropertiesUtil(StandardPBEStringEncryptor configurationEncryptor) {
    CustomPropertiesUtil customPropertiesUtil = new CustomPropertiesUtil ();
    customPropertiesUtil.setSystemPropertiesModeName("SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE");
    customPropertiesUtil.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("mail-dev.properties"));
    customPropertiesUtil.setOrder(1);
    customPropertiesUtil.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(false);
    customPropertiesUtil.setStandardPBEStringEncryptor(configurationEncryptor);
    return customPropertiesUtil;
}
```

The bean configurationEncryptor is defined in XML as:

```
<bean id="configurationEncryptor"  class="org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="config" ref="environmentVariablesConfiguration" />
</bean>
```

Bean B is created in a @Configuration class.
The odd thing is, if I remove the parameter injection shown in Bean B, everything works as expected. However, I need the encryptor to resolve some encrypted properties and the only way it is NOT NULL is to inject it using parameter injection. (see [Why is an @Autowired field within a @Configuration class null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111466/why-is-an-autowired-field-within-a-configuration-class-null))

My question is how come, having a bean injected into the @Bean (Bean B) method cause Bean A to fail?